# Can I call API by passing username/email as alternate in api in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to call this api by passing username as param .or also by passing email as param on at a time using one route.

**Forget Password**

code;

```
router.put('/forget/:username*',function(req,res){
    User.findOneAndUpdate({$or:[{username:req.params.username},{email:req.params.email} ]},
        { "$set": { password: req.body.password}},
        (function(err, user){
            var a = new User({
                username :req.params.username,
                email :user.email,
                password :user.password
            })
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(a);
            }
        }));
    });
```

Comment: You have already asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066120/can-i-add-the-alternate-to-username-as-email-in-passing-parameter-in-api-in-rout . IF you want you can edit that question, Plz avoid duplicate question..

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code 
The route will go like

```
router.put('forgetPassword/:username', controller.forgetPassword);
```

The Controller code as follows :

```
var User  = require(user model path);
module.exports = {
   forgetPassword : function(req, res){
     User.findOne({ $or:[{username:req.params.username},{email :req.params.username}}] 
     },function(err, user){
          if(err)
            console.log(err);
          res.send(user);
     }); 
   };
};
```